# Словообразовательная цепочка слова "полтора"

Tags: словообразование

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить словообразовательную цепочку слова **полтора**.
(Очень надо для проекта.)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4):

***Полтора*** было когда-то образовано из слов ***половина*** и ***второй*** с выпадением звука ***в***:

**пол**(овина) + в**тор**(ой) = **полтора**.

Но в современном русском языке это слово рассматривается как непроизводное с корнем ***полтор*** и окончанием ***а.*** Словообразовательная цепочка для него не составляется.

В "Словообразовательном словаре русского языка" Тихонова включено в раздел "Одиночные слова".

Comment: надо цыпочка а это не надо

Comment: Так я ж Вам написал, что словообразовательной **цЕпочки** это слово в современном русском **не имеет**. И не только это слово...